# How to print the entire matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am taking a column from a matrix and then trying to create an array that averages the column over different increments. I have written a sample code to show my problem.

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numint = 2
numflo = 2.0

a = numpy.matrix ([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]])

b= a[-2*3:,1]

for i in range (0,numint+1,1):
    avg = sum(b[numint*i:numint*(i+1)])/numflo
    print avg
```

when I run this code and I print avg inside the loop I get the following

```
[[ 3.5]]
[[ 9.5]]
[[ 15.5]]
```

but if I print avg outside of the loop then I just get

```
[[15.5]]
```

This throws the rest of my code off. Why does it not print the entire matrix avg and just only the last number. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For every iteration the loop runs and avg gets updated . What you see on the terminal is the intermediate avg of the matrix

Comment: Okay so how can I get it so the loop doesn't write over the previous average, instead creates an array with all 3 averages? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this is because in your `for loop` your are always updating `avg` to the average of the last column you averaged.
 In other words, if you want to have the entire averages you can do something like this as a beautiful one liner:

```
avg = [sum(b[numint*i:numint*(i+1)])/numflo for i in range(0,numint+1,1)]
```

you can then simply access your values normally like `avg[0]` etc..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
avg_list = []
for i in range (0,numint+1,1):
    avg = sum(b[numint*i:numint*(i+1)])/numflo
    avg_list.append(avg)

print (avg_list)
```